# determinism breaks when running a long rigidbody simulation?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I recently tried to create a marble run of sorts where a sphere rolls around obstacles using rigid bodies.

My process was to simulate, adjust things where necessary, then re-bake the simulation- rinse and repeat. I was doing this as I added more to it.

It was all going perfectly this way until suddenly, a precise jump the marble made in all the previous simulations; it was now suddenly missing entirely. It suddenly behaved completely differently! the jump was also very early in the run and was nowhere near the part I was working on- certainly not close enough to affect the sphere.

I believe this is a case of non-determinism in blender's physics engine, which confuses me because I've seen a lot of precise physics simulations made in blender where it would be impossible to create without determinism, so I am wondering what's going wrong that causes the simulation to suddenly stop working the same way as before? If it helps to know and answer, the last obstacle I added was an animated elevator for the marble. Maybe the keyframing caused a weird internal re-grouping of objects in the physics engine?

What can I do to counteract the problem?

Comment: Maybe start by posting some screenshots. Also, insulting people by name here is not a good idea, no matter what made you consider them to be a ****.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Also don't respond to personal attacks with personal attacks. Rude or abusive behaviour will not be tolerated here. Voting on posts is up to users discretion and should reflect the post content alone, not the user who posted it, so don't take it personally. If some user posted rude content, you should flag it for moderator attention, not respond in kind

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos i did, and he just deleted his comments before any action could be taken. honestly everyone im having a really fucking hard time in my life right now. i made one poor decision and im being endlessly bullied for it. please understand that i was attacked, im not the one attacking out of nowhere. also the downvotes on this post show that ppl arent using that feature correctly

Comment: I'm sorry that you are having a rough time, but it is no one else's here fault, don't take out on the wrong people. I didn't downvote your post but I suspect other users did for the lack of information. An image is worth a thousand words, diagnosing issues blindly  from loose descriptions alone is pretty hard. As requested by other users try using the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: I'm not sure why this post got downvotd, but I'm going to upvote it, cos I encountered a similar issue with non-determinism, and Nathan's answer is very useful to me...

Answer (score 3):

Blender's physics are not deterministic.  Or, perhaps more carefully, they depend upon variables that, intuitively, they shouldn't depend upon.  This is true in the short term as well as the long term, although over the long term, smaller differences can grow into larger differences.

However, it's not that the physics future affected the physics past. It's that the two simulations differed in some inobvious way when they started.  This inobvious way may have been the exact time on your system clock, used to seed a random() function.  (I'm not sure *exactly* what they depend on, only that they depend on more than is exposed.)

It is impossible to tell from a rendered animation whether deterministic physics were used.  They are *never* necessary for a render, because *physics* are never necessary for a render.  It is entirely possible to keyframe a simulation-like render by hand.  (It is also possible to combine physics and hand-tweaking in a variety of ways.)

Blender's physics systems are not real physics.  They are good-enough heuristics for when we want some particular thing to get animated and we don't care very much *how* it gets animated.  They are designed less around mimicking the real world than they are around performance and simplicity of parameters.  If we want them to behave the same way whenever we scrub through the timeline, we need to bake the physics.

What can we do if we have some cached rigid body physics that we really like up to a point, but we want to change some things in later keyframes without losing the earlier stuff?  We can set the "current cache to bake" in properties/scene/rigid body world, then bake the physics to keyframes, then recreate the original rigid body physics modifiers, and keyframe the "animated" property to say when we want Blender to use our keyframes and when we want it to use physics.  If we want, we can do that multiple times while animating a scene.